# Java spring Security | JWT csrf token doesn't work on /login

Tags: java, spring-security

i just watched a tutorial for spring security.
I got in a problem, i have a jwt application and wanted to activate csrf.
But it doesn't work for the /login. When i make an path where no authentication is needed the csrf token is working. Only with the path /login it isn't working.

This is my config

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //.csrf().disable()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, secretKey))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig),JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(USER.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
```

I tried to google it myself but the answers were to high for me. Maybe someone can help me in simple words.

The public request with out authentication
[image]

And the /login request where the csrf token wasn't working
[image]

Comment: So i just googled a little and found out that you don't need csrf for jwt. Is that true? 
Or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question, you can refer to the following article to work around that.

https://www.baeldung.com/csrf-stateless-rest-api

Csrf protection can be implemented for REST APIs as per this article as there as certain possible scenarios where the attacker might attempt to steal token from a user's browser storage and use it to access your application's REST endpoint(s).

As per the article

> ***Spring is expecting to receive it in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header***

so you may try to send the token in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header instead of the cookie.